# Is there a way check the internet (cellular data and wifi ) speed in my device using Xamarin Forms for both iOS and Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I'm using a Xamarin Forms application. For checking the internet availability "Xamarin Essentials" is used and the code is

`Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet`

But I need to check if the device internet connection is  slow. Is there a way to implement this in both Android and iOS.

Comment: Just send a block of data to a server and measure the speed.

Comment: Is it like  validating the response from server?

Comment: No, you need to do a performance benchmark. If you measure the time until you get the response, that is the round-trip time. That's not the same as the throughput (data per time). Depending on your application, you might need to check either of the two or both.